# How can I to use JQuery plugin to each row of dataTable (JSF)

Tags: jquery, jsf

I try to use (inject) JQuery plugin to each row of JSF dataTable,
and I have next simple example:

1) JQuery plugin:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.testPlagin = function(param) {
        //do something with param   
        //append internal div etc.
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

2) dataTable (JSF):

```
<h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="order">
    //there will be implemented my testPlagin for each row
    // I was trying add testPlagin bellow, but it is completely not working (and I want to ask ... how it must be?)
    //My attempt:

    <div id="#order">  // in this line I try to add unique Id use hash code of bean
        <script>
            $(document ).ready(function() {

            var divObj = $('#'+ #{order})  // try to get div above
            divObj.testPlagin(#{order.number});

            });
        </script>
    </div>

</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: no need for ID, use class and move your javascript out of the server code loop

Comment: maybe I will add more detail..

Comment: `$('tr div.someClass').testPlagin()` . Make sure plugin is written to return `this.each()` so it will process each element of the collection

Comment: Ok but how can I add to this construction #{order.number}  ??

Comment: use of `data-` attributes would help `<div class="orderClass" data-order="{order.number}">`. Then in plugin use `$(this).data('order')` to read value

Comment: It may be too many questions, but last one =)  If I need to put more than 1 attributes ? Like order.number order.summ etc

Comment: sure .. can have as many attributes as you want. Can also be properly encoded json as value  in one attribute

Comment: thank you =) you have shown me direction

Comment: always best to keep javascript separate from view, much easier to maintain

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?